# sqlserver 2008 or 2005 express cannot install on Windows 7 home?

Tags: windows-7, sql-server, .net-framework, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

When installing 2008 it says it requires .NET 3.5 and 2005 fails : what can I do ?

Answer (score 2):

Download [.Net 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=333325fd-ae52-4e35-b531-508d977d32a6&displaylang=en) from Microsoft

Comment: Have done so but considers it's already installed.

Comment: I did see a computer where the installation was corrupt and would not install because it was already installed. I was able to resolve that issue by using the Windows Installer Cleanup to remove the .Net entry, which allowed the installation to continue.

Answer (score 0):

.NET 3.5 is a prerequisite for installing SQLServer 2008 express.  Download and install .NET Framework 3.5, then try the SQLServer 2008 install.

Answer (score 0):

Better is newest version of .NET.

It's .NET 4 - [link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=0A391ABD-25C1-4FC0-919F-B21F31AB88B7&displaylang=en)

Comment: OK will try 4 maybe it will work

Answer (score 0):

Try to get your install file from [Microsoft's Site](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/default.aspx#Installation_Options), it should download the dependencies by default.

You shouldn't have to download .Net 3.5 separately because it already comes by default with Windows 7.  If that doesn't work, you may need to look for an install of SQL Express 2008 with SP 1 so that it will install on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Installing SQL Server 2008 Express on Windows Home 7 is a bit of a pain, but it is definitely possible.  The system that I'm currently working on is just such a combination (it's also 64-bit).  The link given by Psycho Bob should work for you.  However, if it doesn't I found http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlexpress/archive/2009/06/15/installing-sql-server-2008-guidance.aspx to provide a link to the appropriate package.

Good luck.